# stretching CSS menus across a div

Tags: css

I am working on a website that has a horizontal menu across the top. Here is the example page:
http://workinprogress.pw/test.html

here's my CSS sheet:
http://workinprogress.pw/test.css

I created the menus using the new Son of Suckerfish CSS Dropdown Menus from http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/

What I would like to do is stretch out the menu bar so that the cells assume whatever proportional width they need to have to entirely fill the div container. I would like to avoid absolute positioning or fixed widths because the items in the menu can be changed by the user so I need the menu to always horizontally fill 100% of the containing div regardless of the words that appear in the menu item.

Thanks so much

Comment: You need javascript to do this because css can't tell how many items are present in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'll always have 5 items in this menu, add this CSS :

```
#tbs_horizontal_menus {
    width: 100%;            /* full-width menu */
}
#tbs_menu, #tbs_menu ul {
    padding: 0;             /* clean list padding */
}
#tbs_menu li {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* avoid width problem with border-width */
    width: 20%;             /* 5 x 20% = 100% */
}
```

If this number is variable, add this CSS instead :

```
#tbs_horizontal_menus {
    width: 100%;            /* full-width menu */
}
#tbs_menu, #tbs_menu ul {
    display: table;         /* consider our list as a table */
    table-layout: fixed;    /* width fixed-equal-size columns */
    padding: 0;             /* clean list padding */
    margin-bottom: 0;       /* clean table margin */
}
#tbs_menu li {
    display: table-cell;    /* consider our elements as table cells */
    float: none;            /* make cells NOT floating */
}
```

Comment: menu items are not always 5

Comment: @vlrprbttst That's why there are two parts in my (no-js) answer.

Comment: @zessx the number is variable but when I tried your CSS the menu items simply line up to the left. I need them to stretch out so that look centered. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Are you **sure** `#tbs_menu li` are not floating ? When I tried, there was another rule overriding my `float: none`. Quickly check it using `float: none !important`

Comment: @zessx indeed you were right, I apologize. Thanks for your solution!

Answer (score 0):

this is a basic but effective example: http://jsfiddle.net/n8Jup/1/

basically you can treat the menu wrapper with a `max-width` or a 100% width, and make your menu items "fluid" dividing 100 / menu items. in this case: 5 menu items, so 100/5 = 20% width to the `li`

in case your menu items are variable, you need a javascript solution that counts how many menu items you have and give the proper widths to the `li` like so: http://jsfiddle.net/n8Jup/2/

```
(function() {
            function getCountLi() {
            var count = $("li").size();

                $('li').css('width', (100 / count) + "%");

            }

            getCountLi();


        })();
```

Comment: i updated my answer with the javascript solution too!